# Differen between CORBA and RMI

Tags: java, rmi, corba

I know clearly the difference between CORBA and RMI except a problem about existence of `in`, `out`, `inout`.

CORBA uses IDL language to describe interface and the parameters in the methods defined have the keywords: `in`, `out`, `inout`. Meaning of them is as follows:

- `in`:The parameter is passed from the caller of the operation to the object.
- `out`: The parameter is passed from the object to the caller.
- `inout`: The parameter is passed in both directions.

My question: why are the keywords (`in`, `out` and `inout`) necessary in CORBA but not necessary in JAVA/RMI.

Comment: There are only in parameters in RMI.

Comment: There are only `in` parameters in *Java.*

Answer (score 0):

It's merely a design decision. The main difference in their design is that CORBA is designed to be platform and programming language independent, but RMI is designed especially for the Java programming language.

Many programming languages has their own way to express `in`, `out` or `inout` parameter directions in which languages CORBA IDL has its straightforward equivalent. In other languages (for example Java) these constructs has to be implemented with complex wrapper structures.

The Java programming language does not have `out` or `inout` parameters (although it can be implemented by creating a simple value wrapper class), all parameters are passed `in` by value (for value types) or by reference (for reference types). And since Java itself does not support parameter directions on the language level, it was not necessary to have this in RMI as well.

Answer (score 0):

> but not necessary in JAVA/RMI.

They are not available in Java let alone Java RMI. The designers took the decision to pass everything by value.

Comment: Those keywords are not optional in the IDL. If you write a function in an IDL interface that has parameters you must specify in, out, or inout.